FireFox and Chrome are not loading my css style sheet for a single project. All older projects work as expected
Here is code in my html file where I link to me stylesheet:
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="library1.css">
        <title>Library</title>
        
    </head>

here is what FireFox shows in the style editor:

Here is the full text:
library1.css (0 rules)
line1:
Ⱚ਍㨪戺晥牯ⱥ਍㨪愺瑦牥ൻ †戠硯猭穩湩㩧戠牯敤⵲潢㭸਍ൽഊ⨊ൻ †洠牡楧㩮〠഻ †瀠摡楤杮›㬰਍ൽഊ⸊癥牥瑹楨杮ൻ †眠摩桴›〱瘰㭷਍††敨杩瑨›〱瘰㭨਍਍††楤灳慬㩹朠楲㭤਍††牧摩琭浥汰瑡ⵥ潣畬湭㩳爠灥慥⡴〱‬昱⥲഻ †朠楲ⵤ整灭慬整爭睯㩳爠灥慥⡴〱‬昱⥲഻紊਍਍栮慥筤਍਍††牧摩挭汯浵㩮ㄠ⼠ⴠ㬱਍††牧摩爭睯›‱ 㬲਍††整瑸愭楬湧›散瑮牥഻ †⼠‪慢正牧畯摮挭汯牯›汢捡㭫⨠യ紊਍਍献摩湥癡ൻ †⼠‪楤灳慬㩹渠湯㭥⨠യ †搠獩汰祡›汦硥഻ †映敬⵸楤敲瑣潩㩮挠汯浵㭮਍††牧摩挭汯浵㩮ㄠ⼠㈠഻ †朠楲ⵤ潲㩷㈠⼠ⴠ㬱਍ൽഊ⼊‪渮睥潂歯潆浲ൻ †ഠ紊⨠യഊ⸊慭湩ൻ †朠楲ⵤ潣畬湭›‵ ㄭ഻ †朠楲ⵤ潲㩷㈠⼠ⴠ㬱਍਍††楤灳慬㩹朠楲㭤਍††牧摩琭浥汰瑡ⵥ潣畬湭㩳爠灥慥⡴〱‬昱⥲഻ †朠楲ⵤ整灭慬整爭睯㩳爠灥慥⡴〱‬昱⥲഻紊਍਍愮摤潂歯ൻ †朠楲ⵤ潣畬湭›‱ ㄭ഻ †朠楲ⵤ潲㩷ㄠ⼠㈠഻紊਍਍戮潯獫ൻ †朠楲ⵤ潣畬湭›‱ ㄭ഻ †朠楲ⵤ潲㩷㈠⼠ⴠ㬱਍
if it looks like nonsense, that's because it is.
my css file is filled with correct code. I have even erased all the code and tried just:
*{margin:0;}
but it still fails to load.
I have copied my css code into the style editor as a new stylesheet and it works correctly.
just the external css linking is not working.
I compared my current code to previous projects and cannot find a difference in declaration.
I have restarted my laptop, restarted both browsers.
I cleared my cache and cookies as I saw other "css not loading" issues being resolved by that.
I checked that my pathways are correct, the css, html, and js files are all in the same folder. My external js script loads correctly.
Has anyone else experienced this? I tried looking up the gibberish but nothing comes up.

whats the css file encoding?

You understand that will load "library1.css" from the directory containing the HTML file, right?

please check your encoding of your library1.css  file it should be UTF-8 , one other thing you can do is create a simple css file and try checking in your browser. Make sure to clear your cache before you test, if thats not possible check in incognito

Issue would be in how you link your css file with your html. It must be not linked properly or something.

This is not really a solution, but I just deleted everything and started over, it works now. I tested it and it was the correct path and the html file was utf-8. I created all the files via powershell using "echo $null >> filename" command, maybe that was the issue?

@krward987 Potentially, I just tested echo "something" >> file  in Win10 Powershell and it outputs in UTF-16 encoding. Though I can't reproduce the problem you're seeing even with UTF-16 encoded css file.
